# Trying to copy text to clipboard when selecting an option from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a drop down menu which contains a list of options. I would like to be able to select one of those options, and once selected I would like it to execute a function that copies text from a notepad (.txt file) to my clipboard and alerts me that it's been copied..

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<title>Dropdown Test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeOptions(){
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

if ($(this).val() == "option1")
    function1();
else if ($(this).val() == "option2")
    function2();
else if ($(this).val() == "option3")    
    function3();
else if ($(this).val() == "option4")
    function4();
else if ($(this).val() == "option5")    
    function5();



});

}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

function function1(){
$(function()

{
var page_name="textfile.txt";

    $.get(page_name, function(data)
    {
            if (window.clipboardData) {
    window.clipboardData.setData('text', data);
} 

            alert("The text from textfile.txt has been copied to your clipboard! ");
    });
});
}
 </script>







 <body onload ="changeOptions()">

<select name="dropdown" size=1>
<option>Select options below...</option>
<option value="option1">Text file1</option>
<option value="option2">Text file2</option>
<option value="option3">Text file3</option>
<option value="option4">Text file4</option>
<option value="option5">Text file5</option>

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem here is that it APPEARS to work as when you select from the drop down menu, you get the alert to say " The text from textfile.txt has been copied..."
However, it doesn't copy and I don't know what else to do! I have tried this function with a button and 'onclick' and it works, successfully copying the text to the clipboard!

Please help!

I appreciate it! :)

Comment: http://jonrohan.github.io/ZeroClipboard/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access (copy/paste) to the system clipboard on the client.

To do so would be a security issue.  You could read sensitive data from it, or paste malicious content into it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but the thing is, you can since I have it working with an 'onClick' in an alternate version of this code!

Comment: I guess you are using Internet Explorer?  It has a clipboard API.  Other browsers do not.

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).

Most browsers don't support modifying the user's clipboard directly with javascript for security reasons. There are work arounds using Flash, such as [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard)

Comment: I've just tested this in Internet Explorer and it actually works which is great for what I needed! :D